# Multilanguage application in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently building an application in C# which supports French, English and Spanish. I am using resource files (.resx) to store my text following [this method](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/580043/How-to-make-a-multi-language-application-in-Csharp) I found online. Right now, the resource files I have are the following : TextLabels.resx, TextLabels.en.resx, TextLabels.fr.resx and TextLabels.es.resx.

I use the following method to link my the resource to my form :

```
manager = new ResourceManager("MyProject.TextLabels", typeof(MyForm).Assembly);
```

to change the labels when I have selected a new language, I created a refresh method changes the Text attributes of my containers with the method :

```
Text = manager.GetString("MY_STRING_VARIABLE", culture);
```

Also, I make sure to change the culture used when the user clicks on the desired using the following method :

```
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es"); //changes the culture to spanish
```

So here is my problem : I use a 64 bit Windows 7 computer installed in English (I am not sure if it matters) and this method works fine, all my labels are changed in the desired language. The problem occurs when I try use my project on my colleague's computer which is a Windows 7 32 bits computer in French. Using his computer, it looks as if the program (that I have compiled with Visual Studio 2012) can only find the default resource file (TextLabels.resx). So I am at a loss here and wondering 1. Is the 32 bit system or French installation of Windows the reason of my problem or is it something else and how can I make my application work on his machine?

Comment: I think we need to see some more code to spot the point which is keeping your app from loading resource files other than the default. have you also tested in another computer that is 64 bits with a french installation of Windows 7, or a 32 bits english one?

Comment: Also, if you're using localized binaries, make sure your colleague has them on his computer.

Comment: For testing purposes, make sure you both have the same regional settings in Windows (eg. English US). This caused me a lot of problem in the past and having a common set of settings helped diagnose problems.

Comment: @BrianV Where can I find those localized binaries on my computer?

Comment: @SolarBear I would like to test the program on different regions as I am expecting people to use the application not only in North-America.

Comment: @Renan Thank you for telling me to test it on another x64 computer as I found that it only works on my computer and not any other. I am looking at what BrianV told me to fix the issue.

Comment: They'd be in your bin folder if you're generating them.

Comment: How are you deploying your app? Are you simply copying the files in the bin folder? I vaguely remember that in Visual Studio 2005/.NET 3.5 and previous versions we could have deployment projects, which would make an installer for your other projects in the solution. I know this changed at some point so I don't know how packaging is done now, but do look for a way to have an installer for your app.

Comment: @BrianV Yes I see the ressources.dll thank you

Comment: Thank you, the program works on all our computers now

Comment: @BrianV please post the solution as answer so this question is no longer shown under "unanswered"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are generating localized binaries, be sure that they get deployed with the app.

They would be in the `/bin/Debug` and `/bin/Release` folders.